# Why do we care about planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, planar-graphs

Planar graphs are graphs that can be embedded in the plane. Classic examples of planar graphs are the $1$-skeleton (vertices and edges) of polyhedrons.

Most introductory books on graph theory will have a chapter on planar graphs. **Why are planar graphs important**, besides the characterization of planar graphs being a historical question?

Does knowing that a graph is planar (versus knowing its genus) bring important tools to study it?

Comment: One reason among others: many properties of graphs are connected to the way we can color the vertices, and we have the 4-colours theorem for planar graphs.

Comment: @JeanMarie: can you write more about applications of coloring? I know the solution of the Art Gallery Problem using a $3$-coloring but not much more.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: that sounds like the beginning of an answer. Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 9):

In **"Pure Math"** terms , Planar graphs are interesting objects in themselves. Mathematicians ( like [Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) & [Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem) & [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Plane_graphs) ) analyse those objects to extract interesting theorems.
There are many outstanding conjectures among Planar graphs ( like those by [Harborth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harborth%27s_conjecture) & [Scheinerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheinerman%27s_conjecture) & [Barnette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnette%27s_conjecture) ) hence more work will continue in that Area.

In **"Applied Math"** , general graphs are everywhere. In Particular , Planar graphs are necessary in specialized cases :

- Designing Printed Circuit Boards , MicroProcessors , where the wires are on a Plane.
- Roads & Railway tracks , where crossings will block the traffic or will necessitate costly bridges.
- Irrigation Canals & waterways , where Crossings are not admitted.
- Visualizing large Interconnected temporal or geographical Data , where Crossings will hurt human comprehension.
- Chemistry & Quantum Physics , where the atoms or Particles are connected & Crossings are Prohibited in certain cases.
- Cartographical & Political land-masses are generally Planar.

This [Article Discussing Planarity](http://cs.rkmvu.ac.in/%7Eshreesh/media/planarity.pdf) was generally useful.
There are other online Article too.